# Store objcets in singleton class

Tags: android, static, singleton, object-lifetime

Is it good idea store my data objects in static variables of singleton class? I have class AppEngine where are some data static e.g. boolean int and instances of my classes (Configuration etc.)

When these objects are destroyed?

If I want to use them I call it something like this:

`MyEngine.getMyEngine().getConfiguration().method(arg);`

Comment: yes you can do that, infact this way provide the use of those variable all throughout the app, what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: After some tests, it's appears that these objects are destroyed when the OS kill your process. 
When all activity are finished, data are still in memory..

Comment: u make singleton class and its work ohk so just see my answer it will help u

Comment: A word of caution with static variables - never store a reference to a context in them (that includes activities and views) otherwise you'll leak memory.

Answer (score 1):

no no no dude just put **null** in that object like this

```
singltonclassobject = null;
```

it will destroy. :)